# Rails find or create by in idempotent seeds file - not passing validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to create an idempotent seeds file by using `find_or_create_by` when creating `Users` and their association to each `Account`.

I have created a list of `Accounts` and want to associate a `User` to each account.

The user model has a `uniqueness` validation on the `email`.

On my first run of the seeds file the accounts and users are created and  associated and it works.

However on my second run of the seeds file I get `Validation failed: Email has already been taken`

I get the validation error if I run.

```
Account.first.users.find_or_create_by!(email: email)
```

I am under the impression `find or create by` returns the first record or creates a new record. But it seems to be just creating a new record and not finding the previous user record even though it exists.

If I call

```
User.find_or_create_by!(email: email)
```

The user by that email is returned.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do with `Account.users.find_or_create_by!(email: email)` since Account looks like a class and not an instance thereof. Indeed, `find_or_create_by!` should find the user by those attributes. http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/find_or_create_by%21

Comment: Sorry I updated my question to grab the first `Account` it still doesn't seem to work. hmmm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The user that you are trying to create probably does not exist within that account.

```
Account.first.users.find_or_create_by!(email: email)
```

If there is no user with the email inside of the first account, then it will attempt to create one. However, you can't create that user because the email is taken.

```
User.find_or_create_by!(email: email)
```

That works because it checks for any user, not just a user within the first account.

If you want it to run correctly always, you can do something like

```
Account.first.users << User.find_or_create_by!(email: email)
```

if you know that the users array there is empty. Or possibly,

```
User.find_or_create_by!(email: email).update_attributes(:account_id => Account.first.id)
```

Comment: I guess I am confused I thought `Account.first.users.find_or_create_by!(email: email)` would initially create and associate that user with that account?

Comment: How would I seamlessly make that association? `Account.first.users.find_or_create_by!(email: email, account_id: Account.first.id)`

Comment: @srm Yes, it would create and associate a user with that account. But the create part is not what the problem is, it does not find the user within that users array, so it proceeds to create one. But as you said, there is a user already with that email so the create fails. If you instead find_or_create on the User model, you will find a user instead of creating one.

Comment: I never call the create action other then when I create the user on the account. I guess I need to dig deeper and figure out why the user is not being associated with that account.

Comment: @srm your test data may be persisting in the test database. I haven't seen all of your code, so I'm making some assumptions here, but if on the first run the code is successful, then I am assuming that the second run is unsuccessful because the first time the data persisted and now you have validation errors. Try my code snippets above and see if they will work for you. If you never create them beforehand, then why would you need `find_or_create_by!` in the first place?

Comment: So the next time I run the seeds I wont fail any validations or make duplicate records.